# Copy the directoy in java Using URI

Tags: java, file, copy, uri, dir

Could you please advise me, how to copy the directory from one path to another path(simple way) Using URI.
Kindly provide any examples.

Thanks for looking into this..

Comment: Have you tried anything? Here is a place to get started: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "using URI".  URI could be several things.  It's a type of designator and a class of object (`java.net.URI`).

Answer (score 0):

You should try Apache Commons IO: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/
More specific FileUtils.copyDirectory method: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html